# Google authenticator token is working even after 30 seconds

Tags: google-authentication, google-authenticator

I have configured Google authenticator on Linux and my mfa is working fine, but according to me an MFA token should expire in 30 seconds but even after 30 seconds time I am able to use the token.

If I use the token then it is not reusable but if don't use it within my 30 seconds then I am able to use it after sometime also. Is this normal? I want my token to expire in 30 seconds even I used it or not used it. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 17):

> Although your timestep might only be 30sec, the RFC specifies that the validating service should search the OTP value back and forth in time. This is recommended due to the drift of the clock. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238#section-6

This is why, most systems (including Google itself) allows one previous OTP, so while the code regenerates every 30 seconds, every OTP remains valid for 60 seconds.
You need to check your server-side settings

Comment: No, what I have observed code displayed on my google authenticator app remain valid unless it is used once. I have checked for maximum 150 secs. a code generated remained valid even after 150 secs (duration in which five more codes were generated). but once i have used it it becomes invalid. Why Its So? If these code remains valid after 30 secs then why are shown timer of 30 seconds?

Comment: Depends on the authentication server/system. For example, Azure MFA allows 450 seconds both directions (900 total). This is more to address potential time drift issues

Comment: Yeah! My Gmail accounts code is also valid for more than 150 secs. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

you must to set PeriodDiscrepancy to 0